# Name of British Museum Exhibit on objects of civil disobedience?

Tags: uk, sightseeing, museums, history

I heard on NPR (or BBC) a few weeks ago that there is museum exhibit showing items over the years that were used or iconic of revolution and civil disobedience. I have been looking all over the internet for it and cannot find it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it but if there are others, please post them. http://www.vam.ac.uk/content/exhibitions/disobedient-objects/